# how to get user to input a range from a dialog box

Tags: vba, excel

so i need to get a range from the user, how is it possible to query the user to select a range, something like"

```
dim x as range
x = getrange("Select Range to Compare")
msgbox "The range selected is " & x
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel .  And use Type:=8 for a range input.

Comment: Do you mean have the user select a range of cells/rows/columns (or whatever), or ask them to enter a range like "10-15"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like this. Tweak it as per your requirement.

```
Sub AskUserToSelectARangeToWorkWith()
Dim Rng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select a Range to compare.", "Select A Range!", Type:=8)
If Rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "You didn't select a Range.", vbCritical, "No Range Selected!"
    Exit Sub
End If
MsgBox "The Range selected is " & Rng.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```